# Error in sample ruby program to swap element in an array

Tags: ruby

I created a sample ruby program to swap elements in an array

```
class Swap 
   def swp(a,b)
     self[a],self[b] = self[b],self[a]
     self
   end
   array = [1,2,3]
   array.swp(1,2)
   puts array
end
```

I am getting the following error

```
NoMethodError: private method `swp' called for [1, 2, 3]:Array
    from (irb):77:in `<class:Swap>'
    from (irb):71
    from /home/rahulv/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481/gems/railties-3.2.16/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:47:in `start'
    from /home/rahulv/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481/gems/railties-3.2.16/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:8:in `start'
    from /home/rahulv/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481/gems/railties-3.2.16/lib/rails/commands.rb:41:in `<top (required)>'
    from script/rails:6:in `require'
    from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
```

Please help to fix it.

**UPDATE**

I tried the same program with dynamic array input like this:

```
class Swap 
   def swp(a,b)
     self[a],self[b] = self[b],self[a]
     self
   end
end
puts "enter the array elements "
input = gets.chomp
ary = []
while input != 'fin'
  ary << input.to_i
  input = gets.chomp
end
puts ary
puts "enter the elements to be swapped"
a=gets
b=gets
s=Swap.new
ary = ary.s.swp(a,b)
puts ary
```

Now the output error is like this:

```
enter the array elements  
1 
2 
3 
4 
5
fin
enter the positions to be swapped 
1 
2
NoMethodError: private method `s' called for [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]:Array
    from (irb):17:in `<class:Swap>'
    from (irb):1
    from /home/rahulv/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481/gems/railties-3.2.16/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:47:in `start'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`array.class = Array`, you should add `swp` method for `Array` class.

```
class Array 
   def swp(a,b)
     self[a],self[b] = self[b],self[a]
     self
   end
end

array = [1,2,3]
array.swp(0,1) #The array index start from 0, not 1
puts array.inspect
=> [2, 1, 3]
```

Update:

```
class Array
   def swp(a,b)
     self[a],self[b] = self[b],self[a]
     self
   end
end

puts "enter the array elements "
ary = []
input = 0
while 1
  input = gets.chomp
  if input != 'fin'
    ary << input.to_i
  else
   break
  end
end
puts "enter the positions to be swapped"
a=gets.to_i
b=gets.to_i
ary.swp(a,b)
puts ary.inspect
```

Comment: Your solution works fine. I have updated the question. Kindly check that also

Comment: could you help figuring out the issue?

Comment: `ary.s.swp(a,b)` is wrong, you can't do this, please look my update.

Comment: `ary` is an Object, it don't have s method.

Answer (score 2):

I don't like editing classes like that, for example if there's another class in the ancestor tree that implements the actual `swp` method (for any reason) and you implemented yours, and you try to use the actual documented one, you'll find unexplained behaviour, and it might be uneasy to figure out why it's behaving like that, beacuse your method is hiding, it's more maintainable if you add your methods to the ancestry tree using a module and then including it to the class.

```
module Swappable
  def swp(a, b)
    # method goes here
  end
end
```

Then in another file you would do

```
class Array
  include Swappable
end
```

This way when you call `Array.ancestors` you'd see your module

```
Array.ancestors
=> [Array, Swappable, ....]
```

And when you try something like

```
Array.instance_method(:swp).owner
```

you'll get `Swappable`, while an open class editing would return `Array`

This is just my oppinion on this matter, you can pick whatever works for you.

Comment: I like your solution,it is better for me.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following code blog for take input an array and swap with two positions.

Here I initialize Swap class with an input array and then pass two swap position.

#### Main Class

```
class Swap 
   def initialize(array)
     @array = array#[1,2,3,4,5]
   end  

   def swp(a,b)
     @array[a],@array[b] = @array[b],@array[a]
     @array
   end
 end
```

#### Take Input for array

```
puts "ArrayInput :: Enter numbers separated by spaces, press 'Enter' to finish:"
array = gets
array = array.split(" ")
```

#### Take Input for swap positions

```
puts "SwapInput:: For FirstPosition, press 'Enter' to finish:"
first_position = gets.to_i
puts "SwapInput:: For SecondPosition, press 'Enter' to finish:"
second_position = gets.to_i
```

#### Initialize Swap Class

```
swap = Swap.new(array)
array = swap.swp(first_position, second_position)
puts "Array after swap:"
puts array
```